# Get-Help is not seeing the MAML help files when used against commands in my module

Tags: powershell, powershell-core, maml

I've been trying to improve our PS documentation and started playing with [PlatyPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/create-help-using-platyps?view=powershell-7.2). So far, it's been great, I have nice markdown docs now. I'm also able to generate MAML for use with CLI documentation from it and have been able to remove the doc-comment strings from my modules.

Unfortunately, when I import my module it's unable to see the MAML help files and `Get-Help` for my exported function is very barebones.

My understanding is that when packaging MAML within a module, they need to be placed as follows:

```
MyModuleName/
  |_ en-US/
     |_ MyModuleName-help.xml
```

However, I have done this, but I am still unable to see the proper help documentation from the command line with `Get-Help` or `-?`. This is my first foray into using external help documentation that doesn't use doc-comments, so I'm hoping I'm missing a step or making a MAML beginner's mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was hitting a problem when generating the MAML from the markdown source. I was following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/create-help-using-platyps?view=powershell-7.2) guide to PlatyPS and `New-ExternalHelp` was not generating help for the commands I happened to be testing with.

These commands were not named with the `Verb-Noun` nomenclature, and the files shared a name with their matching function. I took one of the functions and gave it a `Verb-Noun` name instead and did the same with its corresponding `.md` file. With a pattern of `Verb-Noun.md`, `New-ExternalHelp` now generated the command's MAML and placed them inside of `MyModuleName-help.xml`.

---

However, this is not what I wanted. These particular functions are named like commands on purpose, and I do not want to follow the `Verb-Noun` nomenclature for them. An edge case, probably, but I did find a solution for this as well. After a bit of testing, only the command name in the source `.md` file for that command matters as far as MAML generation.

The filename needs to match the `Verb-Noun.md` pattern, but you can have the command called `FunctionName` inside and the help will generate correctly for the command `FunctionName`, not `Verb-Noun`. Now when I import the module, I get the correct help topic for the commands that were previously missing.

Now my `.md` file no longer matches the command name but that isn't the end of the world.